# Does the training set of one topic will be useful to predicate the sentiment for any other topic?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes-classifier, sentiment-analysis

I am working on Twitter sentiment analysis. Now, I should prepare a training data set that fits for any kind of Twitter data that predicts the sentiment of a tweet as pos, neg, and neu.

From googling, I found an air-line tweets training data set with needed labels (pos, neg, neu, and sentiment). When I checked the sentiment of tweets with that training data set, it gave me mixed results. I found that some positive tweets are given as negative and negative as positive.

Is the method that I am following correct or not?

Please suggest your views for preparing a training data set that can predict any kind of the twitter data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have trained your model on air-line tweets, the model will learn the characteristics of the air-line tweets. There could be words used in air-line tweets which are positive and contain great weightage but never even used in other tweets leading to negative results. 
I suggest you to try

1. Get a dataset which contains all kinds of tweets which you desire essentially similar to what your task ahead is.
2. Look into [Transfer learning](ftp://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/machine-learning/shavlik-group/torrey.handbook09.pdf).

Comment: okay.so if i want to get the sentiment on the presidential elections of usa then I need to train the model with that kind of the tweets with correct sentiments and feed the model with that kind of the election tweets only ! Right ?

Comment: Preferably, yes. Then you can get the most accurate results.

Comment: okay!should I maintain same amount of data in my pos,neg,neu training model? or can I go with what I have? I'm have 2k pos,2k neu,7k neg labelled tweets.

Comment: Need not necessarily. You can try with that and hopefully the model will not overfit for the negative tweets. Give it a shot if you have the data and check the results before taking the next step.

Comment: How to eliminate over fitting problem of a model.Neg set dominates the model :( even if I maintain same size.

Comment: Can you train on a bigger dataset?

Comment: not yet , working with count of tweets that I previously mentioned in the comment